# Modifying the forward function in vgg model

Tags: python, pytorch

I need to modify the existing forward method in VGG16 so that it can  pass through the two classifiers and return the value

I tried creating the custom forward method manually and overriding the existing method but I get the following error

```
vgg.forward = forward
```

**forward() missing 1 required positional argument: 'x'**

My custom forward function

```
def forward(self,x):
    x = self.features(x)
    x = self.avgpool(x)
    x = x.view(x.size(0), -1)
    x = self.classifier(x)
    y = self.classifier_2(x)
    return x,y
```

I have modified the default vgg16_bn with one additional classifier as

```
vgg = models.vgg16_bn()
final_in_features = vgg.classifier[6].in_features
mod_classifier = list(vgg.classifier.children())[:-1]
mod_classifier.extend([nn.Linear(final_in_features, 10)])
vgg.add_module('classifier_2',vgg.classifier)
```

My model looks like this after the addition of above classifier

```
(classifier): Sequential(
    (0): Linear(in_features=25088, out_features=4096, bias=True)
    (1): ReLU(inplace)
    (2): Dropout(p=0.5)
    (3): Linear(in_features=4096, out_features=4096, bias=True)
    (4): ReLU(inplace)
    (5): Dropout(p=0.5)
    (6): Linear(in_features=4096, out_features=10, bias=True)
  )
  (classifier_2): Sequential(
    (0): Linear(in_features=25088, out_features=4096, bias=True)
    (1): ReLU(inplace)
    (2): Dropout(p=0.5)
    (3): Linear(in_features=4096, out_features=4096, bias=True)
    (4): ReLU(inplace)
    (5): Dropout(p=0.5)
    (6): Linear(in_features=4096, out_features=10, bias=True)
  )
```

My convolutional layers results are supposed to be passed through two separate FFN layers. So how do i modify my forward pass

Comment: Modifying the `vgg` implementation from `torchvision` wouldn't be a good idea. You should create a [custom module](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/examples_nn/two_layer_net_module.html) where you can define your own forward function.

Comment: But i am testing across different networks, building all of em from ground up is pretty time consuming. The solution given below is sleek

Comment: The answer that you accepted is exactly what my comment describes. Please have a look at the link in my comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best way to achieve what you want is to create a new model extending the `nn.Module`. I'd do something like:

```
from torchvision import models
from torch import nn

class MyVgg (nn.Module):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Net, self).__init__()

        vgg = models.vgg16_bn(pretrained=True)

        # Here you get the bottleneck/feature extractor
        self.vgg_feature_extractor = nn.Sequential(*list(vgg.children())[:-1])

        # Now you can include your classifiers
        self.classifier1 = nn.Sequential(layers1)
        self.classifier2 = nn.Sequential(layers2)

    # Set your own forward pass
    def forward(self, img, extra_info=None):

        x = self.vgg_convs(img)
        x = x.view(x.size(0), -1)
        x1 = self.classifier1(x)
        x2 = self.classifier2(x)

        return x1, x2
```